# How can i show each own values of bars at progressive chart in cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

I completely say what i want to ask in title? how can I show each own values of bars  at proggressive charts. I dont want to shown total values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using 8.X charts and the new 10.X charts. 
You can use the Values property of the chart and set it to Show:
[image: Values Property].

When you run the report, a value of the category will be displayed within its bat. Like this:
[image]

Comment: no I down wan like this. When i set it show it dont show its own value. its show total progressive

Comment: I have tested this solution also on the new 10.X charts and it works (pick Absolute values in the Show Values property).
Which version of Cognos do you use? What exactly type of chart you picked? What kind of model do you use (OLAP / ROLAP / RELATIONAL)? Have you tried to test in Go Sales and retailers samples? If so, did it worked there?

Comment: Thanks a lot. the answer is absolute valus :)